# Azure Function Cosmos DB Output Binding - Custom JsonSerializerSettings

Tags: azure, json.net, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an Azure Function with a CosmosDB output binding, like this:

```
public static class ComponentDesignHttpTrigger
{
    [FunctionName("ComponentDesignInserter-Http-From-ComponentDesign")]
    public static IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "fromComponentDesign")] HttpRequest request,
        [CosmosDB(
            databaseName: StorageFramework.CosmosDb.DatabaseId,
            collectionName: Storage.ComponentDesignCollectionId,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] out ComponentDesign componentDesignToInsert,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var requestBody = new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEnd();
        componentDesignToInsert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ComponentDesign>(requestBody);

        return new OkObjectResult(componentDesignToInsert);
    }
}
```

In this function `componentDesignToInsert` is automatically serialized and put into CosmosDB after the function finishes executing. But the default serialization does not put things in camelCase. For this Json.NET lets you provide custom serializer settings, like this:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourObject, settings);
```

but I'm unsure how I can integrate this with my output binding. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Output binding does not expose the serializer settings at this moment.

One thing you can do though, is leverage your own custom DocumentClient for the operation.

One important thing though is that the DocumentClient instance **needs to be static** (more details on https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Managing-Connections).

```
private static Lazy<DocumentClient> lazyClient = new Lazy<DocumentClient>(InitializeDocumentClient);
private static DocumentClient documentClient => lazyClient.Value;

private static DocumentClient InitializeDocumentClient()
{
    // Perform any initialization here
    var uri = new Uri("example");
    var authKey = "authKey";

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    };
    return new DocumentClient(uri, authKey, settings);
}

[FunctionName("ComponentDesignInserter-Http-From-ComponentDesign")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "fromComponentDesign")] HttpRequest request,
    ILogger log)
{
    var requestBody = new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    var componentDesignToInsert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ComponentDesign>(requestBody);

    var collectionUri = UriFactory.GetDocumentCollectionUri(StorageFramework.CosmosDb.DatabaseId, Storage.ComponentDesignCollectionId);
    await documentClient.UpsertDocumentAsync(collectionUri, componentDesignToInsert);
    return new OkObjectResult(componentDesignToInsert);
}
```

Another option is to decorate the class with `JsonProperty` if that suits your scenario.

Comment: Does this incur more compute cycles because I'm not using the binding?

Comment: No. The binding does a similar thing, it maintains a static DocumentClient underneath, it just doesn't expose it openly to make it more user-friendly. But the binding does not have the full customization.

Comment: So, if I have lots of classes that use this pattern and the same connection parameters, does this get cached or shared behind the scenes?   Or do I have scores of connections, each connected to the same db?

Comment: NM: answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections.